# Цикл for и проверка символов

Tags: python, шифрование, словари

В общем, мне надо чтобы цикл for проверял строку и в зависимости от наличия в строке ключей к словарю, выводил определенные буквы, но загвоздка в том, что ключи словаря могут быть с любым количеством разрядов (не только однозначные). То есть надо каким то образом заставить цикл for проверить строку так, чтобы он в ней обнаружил числа с любым количеством разрядов (например, 690), но как?

```
d = {690: ['п'], 677: ['р'], 837: ['и'], 440: ['в'], 813: ['е'], 770: ['т']}

stroka = '690677837440813770'

for i in stroka:
    if i in d.keys():
        print(d[int(i)], end='')
```

Comment: Учтите, что для того, чтобы это работало, код должен быть префиксным. Т.е. ни один из ключей не должен являться началом другого (например, 23 и 236 быть не должно), т.к. иначе возникнет неопределенность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {690: ['п'], 677: ['р'], 837: ['и'], 440: ['в'], 813: ['е'], 770: ['т']}

stroka = '690677837440813770'

L = len(stroka)

for i in range(L):
    for j in range(i+1, L+1):
        part = int(stroka[i: j])
        # Вторая часть условия чтобы не дублировать подстроки типа 0677 и 677
        if part in d.keys() and stroka[i] != '0':
            print(d[part], end='')
```

Comment: Если коды пересекаются, то посчитаются оба символа, или даже три, если встретится и такая коллизия. Например, сочетание "6770" посчитает за "р" и "т".

Answer (score 1):

1. Сортируешь массив ключей по убыванию длины.
2. Каждый из ключей экранируешь для безопасной вставки в регулярной выражение.
3. Объединяешь экранированные ключи через `|`.
4. Делаешь поиск или замену по регулярному выражению.

Comment: всегда думал, почему qwertiY, ведь имя qwerty не занято..

Comment: @finally, потому что мне нравится именно так - оно не случайное ;)